# How to filter rows by a list of values?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter a dataframe with a list of values. I have a list of addresses. If the 'address' value in a row matches any of the items in the list, I want to leave only those rows in the dataframe. Any ideas?

```
frames = []

for i in address_list:
    bx_house_issue = bx_houses.loc[bx_houses["Address"] == i]
    frames.append(bx_house_issue)
    bx_houses_f = pd.concat(frames)
```

'bx_houses' is the main dataframe that I wanna filter by "Address". 'address_list' is a list of addresses that I want to compare with the address values in the main dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for `isin`

```
ix = bx_houses.Address.isin(address_list)
bx_houses[ix]
```